# accessor and mutator methods in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've heard that eclipse can generate accessor and mutator methods for you but can find it under the different tabs, where exactly is the option to generate accessor and mutator methods automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under 'Source' menu, 'Generate Getters and Setters'

Comment: will that do both accessor and mutator ?

Comment: @noob12: what do you think? What does the name suggest? Did you try it? It's not that hard to actually *try* the suggestion.

Comment: @joachim yes i did and only got one type